# How to upload photos from library to app

Tags: objective-c, uiimagepickercontroller

I'm trying to add an upload image function to my iphone app that way when the user goes to their home page they can upload a photo from their phone and the next time they visit that photo will be the one displayed.

What I have :

```
//Button action to add upload function

-(IBAction)upload:(id)sender
{
    UIImagePickerController *pics = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    pics.delegate = self;
    if ([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary])
    {
        pics.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
    }
    [self presentViewController:pics animated:YES completion:NULL];
    [pics release];
}

- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *) Picker
didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{
    // replace image holder with chosen image
    _imageView1.image=UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
}
- (void)imagePickerControllerDidCancel:(UIImagePickerController *) Picker
{
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];
}
```

Comment: Ah!!!...what are you trying to do with _imageView1.image=UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;???

Answer (score 1):

`UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary` references the entire photo library, giving  user to choose which album.

In your `didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo` method,use

```
_imageView1.image = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
```

**Optional**: How about getting access to device's photo library?..I would basically do it using **AssetsLibrary.framework**.It gives me more options to play with it.

Check out this sample code available in [github](https://github.com/w5mith/WSAssetPickerController).*It provides the ability to select multiple images.It's as easy to setup as UIImagePickerController and it works in both portrait and landscape orientations. It requires the addition of AssetsLibrary.framework. This code uses ARC.*

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *) Picker

    didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {

//replace image holder with chosen image 

 UIImage *pickedImage = [info objectForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"];
[_imageView1 setImage: pickedImage];

}
```